# How can I change the time output of a command to 24-hour format?

Tags: command-line

I am working on a program which requires a time input in the 24-hour format for an if...else statement. It takes this input from a shell command, specifically lpstat. Now, it would be much more convenient for me to take that input in the 24-hour format rather than take a 12-hour input and convert it to a 24-hour input with RegEx.
For reference, my current lpstat output looks somewhat like this:

```
Deskjet_1050_J410-25    nilanjan          4096   Saturday 29 August 2020 04:56:35 PM
Deskjet_1050_J410-26    nilanjan          4096   Saturday 29 August 2020 06:47:14 PM
Deskjet_1050_J410-27    nilanjan          4096   Saturday 29 August 2020 06:58:34 PM
```

In this, I need the time part to be in 24 hours.
Please tell me if what I have to do to get the time output of `lpstat` to be in the 24-hour format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible by setting the `LC_TIME` locale variable appropriately, ex.

```
$ lpstat -a
CUPS-BRF-Printer accepting requests since Thu 05 Apr 2018 05:36:42 PM EDT
DeskJet-3630 accepting requests since Thu 31 Aug 2017 03:59:12 AM EDT
```

but with `LC_TIME=C`

```
$ LC_TIME=C lpstat -a
CUPS-BRF-Printer accepting requests since Thu Apr  5 17:36:42 2018
DeskJet-3630 accepting requests since Thu Aug 31 03:59:12 2017
```